# Angular/Typescript - Reference array of objects within a property from a REST service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple REST service returning JSON similar to the below:

```
{"id":123,
 "name":"Sam",
 "transactions":[
    {"date":"2018-05-31","amount":29.99,"desc":"shirt"},
    {"date":"2018-05-31","amount":42.99,"desc":"pants"},
    {"date":"2018-05-31","amount":59.99,"desc":"shoes"}
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to reference this within the Angular component (.ts) to work with the data.  I'm able to read it fine within the html template using:

```
<tr *ngFor="let transaction of accountTransactions.transactions ">
  <td> {{ transaction.date}} </td>
  <td> {{ transaction.amount}} </td>
  <td> {{ transaction.desc}} </td>
</tr>
```

When I'm in my component, after receiving the value back from the promise, I can access the 'main' properties of the returned data (id and name), but I can't figure out the syntax or method to get at the data within the array:

```
public getAccountTransactions() {
this.apiService.getAccountTransactions(this.acct).toPromise().then(data => {
    console.log('in getAccountTransactions');
    this.accountTransactions = data;
    console.log(data.id);   // this works fine
    console.log(this.accountTransactions.id) // this works fine
    console.log(this.accountTransactions.transactions[0].amount) // this doesn't work
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The data you have listed in your HTML differs from the structure you've provided. `fundName` doesn't exist in your example...

Comment: What do you get if you just console.log(this.accountTransactions)? You may be getting an object with an empty transactions.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work ? you have an error ? if not the first transaction simply miss the property amount

Comment: it look like correct. try using console.log(data) and see what are you receiving

Comment: @tymeJV - corrected that, I had just made some changes to simplify the example.  Regardless, still have the same issue.

Comment: @xrobert35 Yes, I get "Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined"

Comment: When you look in the network tab,  check your request and go to the "response" tab  (in chrome), what do you receive ?

Comment: Can you show the code of apiService getAccountTrans...?

Comment: @xrobert35, sorry, I had pulled the output when querying something that didn't exist in the db.  I deleted my other comment.  I still get the error "Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined, but the output of console.log(data) is {id: 158, transactions: Array(3)}.  In the Network tab, it shows the expected JSON with the 3 entries in the array.

Comment: What is the value of the index 0 of the array?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you show its only a data problem for me

Comment: @xrobert35 Found the issue in apiService.  I had defined the interface for my object as:
interface AccountTransactions {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  interactions: Array<AccountTransaction>;
}
so that last line just needed to be renamed to transactions: Array<AccountTransaction> instead (that's what I get for copy/paste from another interface).  If you post an answer, I'll give you credit as you pointed me to the right place.

Comment: You mean that when you get the result from Server you transform it to match the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually nothing wrong in your code. You should check in the apiService to see if there is something wrong.

Arrray in a normal object in JSON you don't really have something special to do. transactions[0] is simply missing in your object

Comment: thanks, as previously discussed in the comments section, I had used 'interactions' instead of 'transactions' in the interface I defined in apiService which caused this problem.  Appreciate the help.